# Recover lost local changes in Git

Tags: git, recovery

I had a branch with a lot of work done on it, but unfortunately I forgot to commit those changes. Then, I used the command `git checkout -f` which threw away all of my changes.

Is there any way to recover my changes?

Comment: The chances of you being able to recover your work on a force checkout are virtually nil.  `git checkout -f` is a destructive operation on your working index.

Answer (score 2):

There is no facility in git to recover the data unless you either committed it or stashed it.  If you have filesystem-level backups you could use those.  Otherwise, unless losing the data would be more expensive than a crap shoot with a data recovery service, I think you're out of luck on this one.